# Algebraic connectivity of the path $P_n$

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory, laplacian

Let $G$ be a graph with $n$ vertices.
Denote by $L(G)$ the Laplacian matrix of $G$ and
$0=\lambda_1\leqslant\lambda_2\leqslant...\leqslant\lambda_n$ its spectrum.
The number $\lambda_2$ is called the algebraic connectivity of $G$ and
is denoted by $a(G)$.

In my research I need the value of $a(P_n)$, where $P_n$ is the path with $n$ vertices. I know (and I have a proof) that $a(P_n)=4\sin^2(\pi/(2n))$.
It seems that this result is very well-known and classical, but I cannot find a proof in the literature (in some papers the authors just write
$a(P_n)=4\sin^2(\pi/(2n))$ without proof).

Thus I would be very grateful for the reference to a proof of the result
(if the proof exists in the literature).

Comment: here https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166218X1100120X#br000025
it is claimed that the papers [5,6] contain what you need

Comment: [5] R. Grone, R. Merris, V.S.Sunder, The Laplacian spectrum of a graph.

Comment: They refer to the paper of Fiedler: M. Fiedler, Algebraic connectivity of graphs, 1973. But there is NO proof in the paper of Fiedler.

Comment: [6] R. Grone, R.Merris, The Laplacian spectrum of a graph II, 1994. I did not find the result on the algebraic connectivity of the path in the paper.

Comment: Do you need the reference to any proof or to the first published proof ever? You may take the proof say here https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-409-topics-in-theoretical-computer-science-an-algorithmists-toolkit-fall-2009/lecture-notes/MIT18_409F09_scribe2.pdf
if you need a book I would check that of C. Godsil, G. F. Royle (Algebraic graph theory) or Fan R. K. Chung (Spectral graph theory)

Comment: I would like to have a reference to a simple direct proof (as my proof, where I need to know only characteristic polynomial of the adjacency matrix of the path, in terms of the Chebyshev polynomials of the second kind) published in article or book.

Comment: It is Lemma 2.10 on page 69 of my diploma thesis (http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~kratt/theses/rubey.ps.gz), but I am not sure whether you want to reference that.  Unfortunately, I did not know that \cite is an important thing to do back then, but I can check tomorrow whether one of the references fit.  (F.T. Boesch, H. Prodinger does not contain it, unfortunately)